# How to scroll a richtextblock to the end in WinRT

Tags: c#, .net, windows, xaml, winrt-xaml

How do I scroll a richtextblock to the end?  I tried this and some other stuff but it doesnt work.  This scrolls sometimes but never to the bottom :(

```
    <ScrollViewer Name="OutputScroll" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <RichTextBlock Name="ouputRichTextBlock" />
    </ScrollViewer>
```

and after I append the text

```
this.OutputScroll.ScrollToVerticalOffset(this.OutputScroll.ActualHeight);
```

Comment: just a shoot in the dark, but try to use Measure method od RichTextBlock after appending the text.

Comment: yeah that was the problem.  I added UpdateLayout before I scroll and it worked.

Comment: This http://mikaelkoskinen.net/winrt-xaml-automatically-scrolling-listview-to-bottom-and-detecting-when-listview-is-scrolled/ might be of help